# Delete Entry on Front End Form (Craft CMS 4.x)

Tags: frontend-form, craft4

Hello — been reading up on how to do this and there are some posts for Craft 2, 3 — but I'm not sure what's out there works for Craft CMS 4. I am using the following JS to delete an entry. However I get an error in the console log that `http://website.com/actions/entries/deleteEntry can't be found`. What am I doing wrong?

```
<script>
    
$('#delete-entry').click(function() {
    window.csrfTokenName = "{{ craft.app.config.general.csrfTokenName|e('js') }}";
    window.csrfTokenValue = "{{ craft.app.request.csrfToken|e('js') }}";

    var data = {
        entryId: '{{entry.id}}',
        csrfTokenName: csrfTokenValue,
    };
    

  $.post('/actions/entries/deleteEntry', data, function(response) {
      console.log('clickResponse', response);
    }, 'json');

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The delete action has moved to the [ElementsController](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/controllers/ElementsController.php) class in Craft 4, specifically:
https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/7d3351996c5f9f09ea59c0a712df09fc877b753f/src/controllers/ElementsController.php#L966-L1005

Updating your code as follows should work.

```js
    var data = {
        elementId: '{{entry.id}}',
        csrfTokenName: csrfTokenValue,
    };

    $.post('/actions/elements/delete', data, function(response) {
        console.log('clickResponse', response);
    }, 'json');
```

Comment: Amazing thank you! — pointed me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Ben and folks on Discord — here is some form code that also works:

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ csrfInput() }}
    {{ actionInput('elements/delete') }}
    {{ redirectInput('/dashboard') }}
    {{ hiddenInput('elementId', entry.id) }}
    <button value="delete" type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Here is a version that uses JS:

**Link to delete:**

```
<a href="#" id="delete-entry-{{entry.id}}" onclick="deleteEntry('{{entry.id}}','{{entry.title}}')">Delete Entry</a>
```

**JS Code:**

```
<script>
    function deleteEntry(entryId,entryTitle) {
        var data = {
            elementId: entryId,
            sectionId: 1,
            {{ craft.app.config.general.csrfTokenName|e('js') }}: '{{ craft.app.request.csrfToken|e('js') }}',
        };
        let confirmAction = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete the job titled '"+entryTitle+"'");
        if (confirmAction) {
            $.post('actions/elements/delete', data, function(response) {
                console.log('clickResponse', response);
                window.location.reload();
            }, 'json')
        } else {
            //Action Canceled.          
        }
    }
</script>
```